Flutter geolocator plugin telling me to update kotlin version
I've added the geolocator plugin to my flutter app, but it errors out and tells me Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin. I've just created this project, so am using the latest version of flutter, with all the android build.gradle changes. I'm using geolocator: ^12.0.0, i've tried setting the ext.kotlin_version = '2.0.0' in android>build.gradle but the outcome is the same, whether I have explicitly set the version or not
android>build.gradle
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '2.0.0'

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'  // Use the latest version available
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'  // Use the latest version available
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = "../build"
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(":app")
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Full error
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileReleaseKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           11.8s

┌─ Flutter Fix ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                            │
│ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then update │
│ /Users/user/Desktop/Folders/apps/app/android/build.gradle:                  │
│ ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'                                                           │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1


Which flutter version you are using ?

@KalpeshChavda Flutter 3.22.0 Stable channel. Dart 3.4.0

If you are using latest flutter version then make below changes
Remove below code from build.gradle
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '2.0.0'

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'  // Use the latest version available
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'  // Use the latest version available
}

}
Then,
Update the kotlin version in settings.gradle
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
    // The one below. Change the 2.0.0 to the latest version
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "2.0.0" apply false
}
 


Thank you for your answer, This is embracing i have been struggling with this since the last week and today i found your answer thank you.

While this can work, keep in mind it will break some plugins or some functionalities from Flutter that use Gradle and Kotlin, for me it cause unexpected issues at the release.

Click this Button will auto update this and check a logs it will take sometime


This is related to geolocator_android 4.6.0 A workaround is to add 4.5.5 to your dependencies until 4.6.0 gets fixed.
Add the following to dependencies:
geolocator: ^12.0.0
geolocator_android: 4.5.5
Run the following commands:
flutter clean
flutter pub get
Thanks to @rminkler1
https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-geolocator/issues/1517
